# SQL error or missing database (no such table)

Tags: java, database, sqlite

Simple code, I don't know why it's not working. Everything is ok but if I enter any word in textfield that is the output given to me:

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: city)
```

My database is SQLite Studio and my drive is jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar

DB

```
public Connection connect() {

  try {

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:‪‪‪inkingdom.sqlite");

        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

        return conn;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        return null;
  }
}
```

INSERT in SQL

```
@FXML
private void insertIntoAirport(ActionEvent event)  {

    try {

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO city (airport) VALUES(?)");

        pstmt.setString(1, ccity.getText());

        pstmt.execute();
        pstmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Since the error message is pretty clear, should we assume the database actually contains a table named `city`?

Comment: yah i make it table in sqlite studio

Answer (score 0):

Create the table first.

```
$ sqlite3 inkingdom.sqlite
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table city (airport text);
```

Done.

Comment: Does this studio persist the database? Where? Is this place the same place where your Java application is looking for it?

Comment: i solved that my probloem i make database in sqlie studio and saved in dekstop 
but i write in url = "jdbc:sqlite:‪‪‪inkingdom.sqlite";
that database creat in file project 
and method connected in file not in dekstop 
so sorry for that  . now my project has complated ^_^